# How to install vte-ng from the source: make command fails

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, compiling, make

Trying to install [`vte-ng`](https://github.com/thestinger/vte-ng) from source. I did try the usual methods like using `make`. There is nothing related to installing in the `readme` file and could not find a configure folder.

So how do I install this?

Comment: They have a bugzilla site also 'http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=vte'

Comment: bugzilla is used to report bugs right??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should generate the `Makefile` from `Makefile.am`. For this follow the below instructions:

1. Make sure you have **`autoconf`**, **`libglib2.0-dev`**(for AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT macro), **`gtk-doc-tools`** installed.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install autoconf libglib2.0-dev gtk-doc-tools
   ```
2. Get inside extracted source folder, then run autoreconf

   ```
   cd ./vte-ng-0.42.4.a
   autoreconf
   ```
3. If you got any error run

   ```
   automake --add-missing
   ```
4. Finally, build and install

   ```
   ./configure && make && sudo make install
   ```

Comment: As you answered the other question  but not accepted by the other user & your question here asked before his. Conceder copying  full instructions here then accept it. We flag others as duplicate of this one. I think this will be cleaner fix for the 3 questions.